# Парсер фото разного размера из группы ВКонтакте

Tags: php, парсер, vkontakte-api

Всем привет. 
Я только учусь :)
Делаю сайт для автодрома горячийлед.рф, дошел до галереи. Просто копируем из альбомов группы ВК.
Пишу скрипт с целью получить массив ссылок на превьюшки и на большие размеры.
Вчера составил запрос, теперь вот разгребаю результат :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php

// Отправляем запрос
$get = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?v=5.74&owner_id=-101740574&album_id=251725522&photo_sizes=1&count=5"); 

// Преобразуем JSON-строку в массив
$urls = json_decode($get); 

//получаем массив ссылок на элементы (картинки)
$urls = $urls->response->items;

//берем первый элемент
$urls = $urls[0]->sizes;

//смотрим третье значение - размер р
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($urls[2]);

//выводим путь картинки
echo $urls[2]->src;
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Вроде в правильном направлении иду.
Кто подскажет способ покрасивее? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> с целью получить массив ссылок на превьюшки и на большие размеры

дак и получайте массив, а потом с ним работайте.

```
$data = json_decode($get, true);
$items = $data['response']['items'];

$images = array_map(function($v){
                  return [
                     'preview' => $v['sizes'][2]['src'],
                     'large'   => $v['sizes'][8]['src'],
                  ];
             }, $items);
```